# Which way should I call an inherited static method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

When a class in JavaScript extends a class that has a static method, it is possible to call that method by referencing it from either the Parent class or the Child class, the results look the same, but is there any difference between them?

Example:

```js
class MyParentClass {
    static myFunction() {};
}

class MyChildClass extends MyParentClass {
    anotherFunction() {
        MyParentClass.myFunction();
        MyChildClass.myFunction();
    }
}
```

Both `MyParentClass.myFunction();` and `MyChildClass.myFunction();` both result in the same function being called. Should I be using one over the other, or is there no difference at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is easy, when you call `parent.foo();` you are calling the parent's implementation of that function, by calling `child.foo();` you are calling the child's implementation.

If you just want to call the parent's function and don't override the method in the child class there is indeed no difference between both invocations. But there is in this example:

```js
class Parent {
    static foo() {
        console.log("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static foo() {
        console.log("Child");
    }

    bar() {
        Parent.foo(); // will print "Parent" to the console
        Child.foo(); // will print "Child" to the console
    }
}
```

Judging from this example I would suggest to always invoke `child.foo()` to make it easier to maintain the code. If will overwrite the function `foo()` in the future and are calling `parent.foo()` but want the result of `child.foo()` it will take you a while to find the mistake.

You should only invoke `parent.foo()` if you explicitly need the result of the parent's implementation.

Comment: This seems like it would make for a good linting rule, any idea if this exists in tslint or eslint? :)

Comment: Probably not since this is a very opinionated rule and you can't detect which function would be the correct to invoke just from looking at the source code